# How to iterate a command with two different variables?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Using kernel 2.6.x

GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (arm-openwrt-linux-gnu)

In a bash script, how would you write a for loop that produces the following result with the variables below ?

```
command option option abc option 10
command option option def option 20
```

VAR1="abc def"

VAR2="10 20"

I can iterate $VAR1, but I don't know how to iterate $VAR2.

```
for i in $VAR1; do
command option option "$VAR1" option "$VAR2"
done
```

Should the command line be split into two strings, iterated separately and then concatenated ?

How about using a count variable with an array ? For example ...

```
count=1
echo ${VAR1["$count"]}
```

Could a count variable with a while loop work ?

Comment: Are you trying to get all permutations of the combinations of the two variables?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17409966/5199222) on SO do what you want?

Comment: Updated the result example.

Comment: @DopeGhoti - The relationship between the variables would be 1:1. For example, the first values of each variable would be used - abc and 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
arr1=(abc def)
arr2=(10 20)
```

And then:

```
for (( i=0; i<${#arr1[@]}; i++ )); do echo "${arr1[i]} ${arr2[i]}"; done
abc 10
def 20
```

In your case, the echo statement will then look like:

```
for (( i=0; i<${#arr1[@]}; i++ )); do 
    echo "command option option ${arr1[i]} option ${arr2[i]}"
done
command option option abc option 10
command option option def option 20
```

Look [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/c_for) for examples on a C style for loop in bash.

Comment: I'm getting an error on the first variable line - syntax error: unexpected "(". Quoting the variable values gets rid of that error, but creates another error - syntax error: bad for loop variable.

Comment: Strange. Works fine on Debian Stretch with: `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: @uihdff, that's an error message typically reported by `busybox` `sh` (based on `ash`, that doesn't have array support), not `bash`. You're not having this code interpreted by `bash`.

Comment: #!/bin/sh is at the top of the script and the commands followed on the next lines. Running "bash --version" reports "GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (arm-openwrt-linux-gnu)". Why is ash being used ?

Comment: Had to change the shebang to "#!/opt/bin/bash". It's working now. Tack så mycket !

Comment: @maulinglawns - Is there a way to do this with sh instead of bash ?

Answer (score 3):

It's easier with `zsh`:

```
$ a=(a b c) b=(1 2 3)
$ for i j (${a:^b}) echo "i: $i, j: $j"
i: a, j: 1
i: b, j: 2
i: c, j: 3
```

`${a:^b}` is the array-zipping operator (expands to `a`, `1`, `b`, `2`, `c`, `3` above).

If you wanted to loop over words resulting of the split+glob operator applied to `$VAR1` and `$VAR2` in a POSIX-like shell (like the busybox `sh` you seem to be using according to the comments to @maulinglawns's answer), you could use the positional parameters.

```
VAR1='a b c'
VAR2='1 2 3'
set -- $VAR1
for j in $VAR2; do
  echo "i: $1, j: $j"
  shift
done
```

Comment: Did the for line need ";do" at the end ? Thanks for the help.